Conceptual proof of Jacobi-like identity for Toda brackets
In the paper $p$-primary components of homotopy groups IV, Toda proved an identity for his bracket operation, which can be succinctly written as
$$[[\alpha, \beta, \gamma], \Sigma \delta, \Sigma \epsilon] + [\alpha, [\beta, \gamma, \delta], \Sigma \epsilon] + [\alpha, \beta, [\gamma, \delta, \epsilon]] = 0.$$
Here we have five maps $X_1 \xrightarrow\epsilon X_2 \xrightarrow\delta X_3 \xrightarrow\gamma X_4 \xrightarrow\beta X_5 \xrightarrow\alpha X_6$, such that the composition of consecutive pairs are zero. $\Sigma \alpha$ is applying the suspension functor to the map $\alpha$. This is quite pretty an identity, and the proof is elementary: Toda performs some intricate manual homotopies of 2-paths, which makes everything magically cancel out.
This is a little bit unsatisfying for me. Why should we expect this identity to be true? Graphically, the 2-homotopies involved consists of interlocking maps and null-homotopies, which makes it quite easy to lose track of the boundaries and perform "illegal" homotopies. In particular, you can't freely move the 2-paths around as if we were in a little 2-cubes operad.
This question also stems from attempting to formalize this argument in type theories, where homotopies are represented syntactically in a manner similar to simplicial or cubical sets. So Toda's proof is very cumbersome to adapt. (It involves piecewise-linear functions in polar coordinates!) I'm wondering if there is some deeper reason that the identity is true, so that we can write a more streamlined proof in cubical type theory.

Is it true that $[\alpha,\beta]=0$ etc for all combinations?

@Pedro What is $[\alpha, \beta]$? If you mean $[\alpha, \beta, \gamma]\circ\Sigma \delta = 0$ (necessary for the outer Toda bracket to be defined) then yes, some of these are hypotheses and some are necessarily true.

You don't have binary brackets defined on these classes?

@Pedro you could argue that the binary version is just function composition. This fits in a family of "higher Toda brackets" of arbitrary arity.
